# facing while storing data from a form

Tags: ruby, mongodb, ruby-on-rails-4

I am finding difficulty while trying to signup .After filling all the fields of the new.html.erb when i am clicking on Register button,i am getting error something like this:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vyWWb.png)
After clicking on register,it is rendering the same page,but with the list of errors and making all the empty.I could not able to figure out why it is not saving and another thing is why it is giving those errors,if i am filling the whole field.

Here is my program

**new.html.erb**

```
   <%= form_for @user, :html=> {:id => 'create_user'} do |f| %>
  <div class="text-center" style="font-size:16px;color:red;">
    <% if @user.errors.any? %>
      <ul>
          <% @user.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
            <li><%= msg %></li>
          <% end %>
        </ul>
      <% end %>
    </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.text_field :name, class: 'form-control', placeholder: 'Enter Name' , name: "name" , id: "name" %>

  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.text_field :category, list: "category", id:"select", placeholder:"Select By category" %>
      <datalist id="category">
        <select>
          <option value="Student" />
          <option value="Faculty" />
          <option value="HOD" />
          <option value="Principle" />
          <option value="Dean" />
          <option value="Chairman" />
        </select>
      </datalist>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
     <%= f.email_field :email, class: 'form-control', placeholder: 'Email' , name:"email" , id: "email" %>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.password_field :password, class: 'form-control', placeholder: 'Password' , name:  "password" , id:"password" %>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation , placeholder: "Re-type Password" , class: "form-control" , name:"password_confirmation", id:"Re_type"  %>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="row" style="margin-top:20px;">
      <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2 col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1 col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1">
        <%= f.submit "Register", class: "btn btn-primary btn-block disabled" , id: "register" %>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

**routes.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root "users#index"
  get '/' => "users#index"
  get "/new" => "users#new"
  resources :users
  post "/users" => "users#create"
  get "users/:id" => "users#show"

  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
end
```

**users_controller.rb**

```
Class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def index
  end

  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def show
  end

  def create
    @user = User.create(user_params)
    puts "======================================================================"
    puts @user
    puts "======================================================================"
    if @user.save
      session[:user_id] = @user.id
      flash[:success] = "Welcome to the My project!"
      redirect_to user_path(:id)
    else
      render :new1
    end
  end

    private

    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:name,:category, :email, :password)
    end
end
```

**user.rb**

```
class User
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :name, type: String
  field :category, type: String
  field :email, type: String
  field :password, type: String
  validates :name, presence: true ,format: { with: /\A[a-zA-Z]+\z/} 
  validates :email, presence: true , format: { with: /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i } , uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false } 
  validates :password , presence: true 
  before_save :downcase_fields

  def downcase_fields
    self.name.downcase!
    self.category.downcase!
    self.email.downcase!
  end
end
```

Please help me out.
I am using mongodb as backend and trying to store the data from the form fields but it is showing error always. It is neither storing the valid data into the database.

Comment: What is the error? Please add it to your question.

Comment: Gerry, i had made changes to the post and i had also attached the image containing the error.Please help me out to solve this problem .

Comment: What are you  getting on `params` ?

Comment: sorry, i did not get you,can u please elaborate?

Comment: in the terminal i am getting something like this:Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"/ahxdSplyNT887KUyy5P911/SaxF/vNjns+TseUKAx38sxBRGFgXPbFdArhJ1IyfqJkIEWZSU3OaG7/SgJCH6A==", "name"=>"tej", "user"=>{"category"=>"Student"}, "email"=>"tej@gmail.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]", "commit"=>"Register"}

Comment: There are the things along with above in the terminal:MONGODB | localhost:27017 | my_project_development.find | STARTED | {"find"=>"users", "filter"=>{"email"=>nil}, "projection"=>{"_id"=>1}, "limit"=>1}
MONGODB | localhost:27017 | my_project_development.find | SUCCEEDED | 0.000512337s
MONGODB | localhost:27017 | my_project_development.find | STARTED | {"find"=>"users", "filter"=>{"email"=>nil}, "projection"=>{"_id"=>1}, "limit"=>1}

Comment: MONGODB | localhost:27017 | my_project_development.find | SUCCEEDED | 0.000415519s
  Rendering users/new1.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered users/new1.html.erb within layouts/application

Comment: When i am trying to print the PARAMS,using the following command Rails.logger.info("PARAMS: #{user_params.inspect}"), the result on the terminal is:                                                                                        PARAMS: <ActionController::Parameters {"category"=>"Student"} permitted: true>

Comment: Improve the title of question. It's terrible. Not descriptive at all and isn't even in valid english (facing what?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your mistake is overriding `name` and `id` on your inputs. Mainly `name`.

```
<%= f.email_field :email, class: 'form-control', placeholder: 'Email' , name: "email" , id: "email" %>
                                                                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Drop those and it should work.

---

Explanation: by rails conventions, in this case name should be `user[name]` and id should be `user_name`.

Because name is not `user[name]` your strong params method discards it. It expects `name` to be nested under `user`

```
 params.require(:user).permit(:name)
```